# No view found for id 0x7f0a007d (com.fahim69.bazaarapp:id/category_container) for fragment FruitCategory{adff339}

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an ecommerce app where in an activity there is a bottom nav bar and a container the fragments which will be show while navigating using nav bar. All are working fine but when I tried to move from category fragment to fruit category frament then I am facing this errors.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a007d (com.fahim69.bazaarapp:id/category_container) for fragment FruitCategory{adff339} (c30c5727-8cec-4fec-b560-c8f066427df4 id=0x7f0a007d)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

My Category fragment code is given below:

```
package com.fahim69.bazaarapp.Fragment;
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
CardView fruit, fish, meat, vegetable, cooking, dairy, frozen, snacks, bread, beverage, 
personal_care, hygiene, baby_care, homekitchen, petcare;
ImageView fruit_img, fish_img, meat_img, vegetable_img, cooking_img, dairy_img, frozen_img, 
snacks_img, bread_img, beverage_img, personal_img, hygiene_img, baby_img, home_img, pet_img;
TextView fruit_tv, fish_tv, meat_tv, vegetable_tv, cooking_tv, dairy_tv, frozen_tv, snacks_tv, 
bread_tv, beverage_tv, personal_tv, hygiene_tv, baby_tv, home_tv, pet_tv;


public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    fruit = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitname);
    fish = view.findViewById(R.id.Fish);
    meat = view.findViewById(R.id.meat);
    vegetable = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable);
    cooking = view.findViewById(R.id.cooking);
    dairy = view.findViewById(R.id.dairy);
    frozen = view.findViewById(R.id.frozenAndCanned);
    snacks = view.findViewById(R.id.Snacks);
    bread = view.findViewById(R.id.breadandbakery);
    beverage = view.findViewById(R.id.beverages);
    personal_care = view.findViewById(R.id.Personalcare);
    hygiene = view.findViewById(R.id.Hygiene);
    baby_care = view.findViewById(R.id.BabyCare);
    homekitchen = view.findViewById(R.id.HomeandKitchen);
    petcare = view.findViewById(R.id.Petcare);


    fruit_img = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitpic);
    fish_img = view.findViewById(R.id.fish_category_img);
    meat_img = view.findViewById(R.id.meatpic);
    vegetable_img = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetablepic);
    cooking_img = view.findViewById(R.id.cookingpic);
    dairy_img = view.findViewById(R.id.dairypic);
    frozen_img = view.findViewById(R.id.frozenandcannedimg);
    snacks_img = view.findViewById(R.id.snackscatimg);
    bread_img = view.findViewById(R.id.breadandbakeryimg);
    beverage_img = view.findViewById(R.id.beveragesimg);
    personal_img = view.findViewById(R.id.personalcare_img);
    hygiene_img = view.findViewById(R.id.hygiene_img);
    baby_img = view.findViewById(R.id.babycare_img);
    home_img = view.findViewById(R.id.homeandkitchen_img);
    pet_img = view.findViewById(R.id.petcareimg);


    fruit_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name_tv);
    fish_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.fish_category_tv);
    meat_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.meat_cat_tv);
    vegetable_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable_cat_tv);
    cooking_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.cooking_cat_tv);
    dairy_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.dairy_cat_tv);
    frozen_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.frozen_cat_tv);
    snacks_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.snacks_tv);
    bread_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.breadbackery_tv);
    beverage_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.Beverage_tv);
    personal_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.personal_care_tv);
    hygiene_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.hygiene_tv);
    baby_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.babycare_tv);
    home_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.homeandkitchen_tv);
    pet_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.petcare_tv);


    fruit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new FruitCategory();
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.category_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

---

**FruitCategory.java**

```
package com.fahim69.bazaarapp.Category;
public class FruitCategory extends Fragment {
RecyclerView fruitrv;


public FruitCategory() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fruit_category, container, false)
    return view;
}
```

}

I am new to fragment and not so much expert so please help me out!

Comment: It's saying you don't have a view in your layout with the ID ``category_container``, which you're referring to in the line `transaction.replace(R.id.category_container, fragment)`. Make sure you have a container view in your Activity's layout with that ID - there's more info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove

Comment: I have an activity where a constraint layout id is category_container. So I have that view actually.